# Design approach cassandra for Rowkey and already exists check

Tags: cassandra, uuid

I am new to cassandra and my cassandra is giving lot of read timeout errors..tweaked timout but still problem may be problem with design (for my application cassandra expected to store trillions of data):

Question 1 : In an all my cassandra tables i use UUID as rowkey...but for few tables just for maintainence i break that rule like in user table i make email id as rowkey....so that looking at tables i can understand data stored...IS using UUID right approach for huge case and second approach for user table is right or not ???????????

Question 2 : i have one relations table with startNodeId, relationTypeId, endNodeId...rowkey for that is UUID which is relationId.....i define secondary indexes on startNode, relationType, endNode as i can have lookup by any of them by business case.........becuase of that for each new row i have to do get to check ALREADY existing relation or not....One approach to avoid existing check is :  i take startNodeId, relationTypeId, endNodeId SORT them and create HASH CODE and use that as ROWKEY...so my already checking explicitly will be avoided here..........IS THIS RIGHT approach ???????

Please guide me i am stuck at these thoughts...any guidance will really help me

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your first question, until and unless you are comfortable in handling the rowkey with non-uuid value, its great also easier to track else go for the UUID.

Regarding to your second question, why don't you try the [compound key](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cql-3-0). You don't have to maintain hashcode like stuffs, leave it on Cassandra.

Comment: thanks for guidance...i am using THRIFT apis...not using CQL....do not know what is better as my case is handling terabytes of data so thought of sticking to thrift as CQL would add some overhead...can i use compound key in thrift or CLI ??

Comment: you should try with cql3 in cassandra 1.2+ series

Comment: actually most of code already written...so do not have option to rewrite all apis in CQL....my main doubt is if row keys are not UUIDS..if we use custom stings then does that degrade peformance of cassandra..

Comment: thanks much abhi..i cannot switch to CQL so no option of compound key BUT to avoid EXISTS check for each insert...i can create hashcode for sorted string made of startNodeId, relationTypeId, endNodeId..use that as rowkey...as in this table i need to ensure startNodeId, relationTypeId, endNodeId UNIQUE....any other BETTER solution you can suggest ??? i am not confident on this...

Comment: Almost every client now a days support compound keys. So may be you should look after that thing also. If you are using astyanax then check this http://brianoneill.blogspot.in/2012/10/cql-astyanax-and-compoundcomposite-keys.html

Answer (score -1):

1) Better use natural keys not UUIDs. Email, timestamp, composite primary keys, and so on. Using UUID is an approach from RDBMS world, you should avoid it in Cassandra

2) Read-modify-update is wrong pattern for Cassandra. Try rewritng data, if your business case allows this. Or just use timestamp and get the row with latest timestamp (don't forget about TTL).

Comment: thank you very much..it will be helpful if you can me give link to reference code as alternative to UUID...that will really help me....                                                                                                                                  Second yes i am changing readmodifyupdate approach..for few tables i am moving away from thrift and will use CQL so that i can define composite keys....internally cql table storage will make sure existing keys are updated...i had started using datastax java driver but getting error "No handler set for stream 0"..please guide me